# Saving Logcat content to local storage but it suddenly stops

Tags: android, logcat

I have implemented a solution

```
try {
            var process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat ${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}:V brief output")
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + "/storage/emulated/0/"+"Logging.txt")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

This works for a few minutes and then stops on Android 10. Any idea what could be the reason that it stops writing log to the file?

Comment: What is file size of logfile when it stops?

Comment: Around 25-40 kb